# Splitting a text

Tags: python, list, text, split

I have a large text in which three people talking. 
I read that text to a string variable in python.

Text is like

> JOHN: hello
>
> MIKE: hello john
>
> SARAH: hello guys

Imagine a long talk between 3 people. I want to split the texts into lists like

```
john = []
mike = []
sarah = []
```

and I want the list john to contain every sentence john said.

Can anyone help me with the code I need?

Comment: You're being downvoted because you haven't shown any effort. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is enough to get you started.

```
for line in text:
    if line.startswith('JOHN'):
        john.append(line)
    elif line.startswith('MIKE'):
        mike.append(line)
    elif line.startswith('SARAH'):
        sarah.append(line)
```